# Determinant of a matrix in the form of $X'\Sigma X$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let $X \in \Bbb R^{n \times p}$, where $n > p$, be a tall matrix of full column rank. Let $\Sigma = \text{diag}\{\sigma_1, \ldots, \sigma_n\}$ be a diagonal matrix and $\sigma_i > 0$, $i = 1,\ldots,n$ are not all identical. Is there a way to calculate the determinant $|X'\Sigma X|$ without the need to compute the matrix multiplication?

An initial thought was to link the eigenvalues of $X'\Sigma X$ to $\sigma_i$ and SVD (or some decomposition, e.g. QR) of $X$ but it didn't yield anything useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to use the [Cauchy Binet formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Binet_formula). In the notation of the linked page, we have
$$
\det(X'\Sigma X) = \det([\Sigma^{1/2}X]'[\Sigma^{1/2}X]) = \sum_{S \in \binom{[n]}{p}} \det((\Sigma^{1/2} X)_{S,[p]})^2
\\ = \sum_{S \in \binom{[n]}{p}} \det(\Sigma_{S,S}) \det(X_{S,[p]})^2
\\ = \sum_{S \in \binom{[n]}{p}} \det(X_{S,[p]})^2\prod_{k \in S}\sigma_k.
$$
This avoids the matrix computation, but I'm not sure if it ends up being any easier for your purposes.

Comment: Thanks Ben. This is exactly what I'm looking for. I can now pre-calculate all $\text{det}(X_{S,[p]})$ which should speed up the computation.

Comment: Great, glad to help